# Azure management.core Api Unable to create a workspace

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-resource-manager, azure-management-api

Hello am trying to create a machine learning work-space using ARM using management api but, getting error "The resource service name machinelearning is not supported".

Can someone help with whats wrong here or do i need to update to management.azure if so how.?

[https://management.core.windows.net/{Subc-id}/cloudservices/MyApp/resources/machinelearning/~/workspaces](https://management.core.windows.net/%7Bsubid%7D/cloudservices/MyApp/resources/machinelearning/~/workspaces)

Answer (score 0):

As per this -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#request-uri documentation, Azure Resource Manager (ARM) provider APIs use https://management.azure.com/, and Azure classic deployment model uses https://management.core.windows.net/

I think its better to refer this -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/machinelearning/ to check for what all machine learning API calls are supported.

Hope this helps!! Cheers!!

Comment: Not really the documentation does't provide any info on API REFERENCE of management.core.windows.net